# Can't hear audio in incoming chan_mobile calls

Tags: raspberry-pi, asterisk

I have set up [RasPBX](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/) on a Raspberry Pi 1 using chan_mobile to forward calls to and from a mobile phone to a SIP client using the both the instructions for plain Asterisk [here](https://jtanx.github.io/2016/02/24/using-asterisk-to-route-calls-through-mobile/) and via FreePBX [here](https://pbxinaflash.com/community/threads/chan_mobile-and-bluetooth-with-piaf-reliable.16533/). In both cases outgoing calls (from SIP client via mobile) work fine but on incoming  calls (to mobile forwarded to SIP client) the caller can hear the receiver but the receiver cannot hear the caller.

A found a [post](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspbx/discussion/general/thread/51062a70/) with a similar issue that suggested to force USB to 1.1 using the [dwc_otg.speed=1 boot option](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=6008&p=188040) but that didn't work as my case is different in that the issue only happens on incoming calls.

How can I diagnose and fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem with: https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30661088-PBX-FreePBX-for-the-Raspberry-Pi when using Asterisk 13 or Asterisk 14. There is NO problem if Asterisk 11 is used. This leads me to believe the problem is with Asterisk 13/14, but I've been unsuccessful at getting Digium to investigate it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I worked around the problem by downgrading to Asterisk 11.

Answer (score -2):

Fix No audio inbound Chan_Mobile !!!!..

EXSTENSIONS_CUSTUM.CONF
[A12]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(Mobile/A12/${EXTEN},45) _X.,n,Hangup
[incoming-mobile]
exten => s,1,Noop(Entering macro-from-mobile-custom-1 with DID = ${DID} and setting to: 0123)
exten => s,n,Set(__FROM_DID=0123)
exten => s,n,Goto(from-trunk,0123,1)-Mobile]

MAKE DID NUMBER 0123  point to Queue and if you don't an send it to extensions you get no audio